# Facebook Deep Linking with swift

Tags: ios, swift, facebook, deep-linking

I want to integrate facebook deep kinking with my application.
I search out for related documents and examples, but could not find.

[This link](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/applinks/ios) (facebook developers) only describe Handling incoming links , Adding back navigation.

Which I want to find, how to post on facebook using facebook deeplinking.
I also include images in my facebook post , when user click on that image then If my app already installed in device then open app ,not installed then open app store.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, You have to enable Deeplinking From your Facebook App

After setting up your Facebook app, You can share Image on Facebook with Facebook SDK, [Facebook Ref:](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/ios)

You can also pass extra parameter for Deep linking with Facebook Graph API [Check out similar link, That will help you](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20684468/facebook-deep-linking-with-ios-app)